# Having trouble connecting to wifi on Fedora 14

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, fedora, gnome

I'm relatively new to Linux and I've recently downloaded Fedora 14 to run as a dual boot with Windows 7. I've tried using a wired connection and it works fine, but when it comes to wifi, I'm getting nowhere. I've tried using the network manager and adding a new connection, inputting the correct SSID etc. But the option to connect to wifi never appears in the taskbar, so I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong. If it helps, I'm using Gnome as a desktop environment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 14 is an older release (and not supported anymore). It's likely that your Wifi card is supported by newer drivers in Fedora 17, but not in the older release you tried. Get a newer Fedora release from http://fedoraproject.org/get-fedora, and odds are very good that this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could give the output for the command

```
$lspci.
```

This will display information about PCI buses in the system and devices connected to them. From here, we'll get the name of the vendor who has made the wifi module used in your system.

Then one can look for open source drivers and compile them accordingly. If one is still unsure, you can follow the guide [here](http://commandlinewani.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-install-ethernetwirelessbluetoot.html):